# Unexpected outcome of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create a graph for a voting app, see the image below.

It works pretty well, but there is an unexpected behavior while crafting the bars with extended width and reduced opacity. They are calculated by the sum of each result within a "0-4" or "5 to 9" range.

This example set given, I expect another result than ng-repeat produces.

```
{"0":2,"5":4,"10":0,"15":2,"20":1,"25":1,"30":1,"35":0,"40":0,"45":0,"50":0,"55":1,"60":0,"65":0,"70":0,"75":1,"80":7,"85":10,"90":3,"95":0}
```

This fiddle shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/r9usr4g1/2/ and compares real and expected result.

Can you explain my mistake and a solution?

Kind regards,
Patrick

[image: results by percent]

Comment: The problem here is that JS Object keys get sorted alphabetically by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment: The problem here is that JS Object keys get sorted alphabetically by default

To avoid this from happening you can use a filter. I updated your jsfiddle using a toArray filter.

```
myApp.filter('toArray', function () {

return function (obj) {
    console.log(obj)
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
        return obj;
    }
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(obj, function(obj, key) {
        obj.$key = key;
        result.push(obj);
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rmdjndjv/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your representation, make sure you have it like this instead.

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in ResultAreaSum track by $index' title="{{ResultAreaSum}}">
        <td>{{ $index + '-' + result}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you `track by $index`, you will know that it will be presented in the same order as the array displays it, not in alphabetical. Since object will be displayed in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

this is because angular reformat the object according to object keys
for EX:

```
{"0":2,"5":4,"10":120,"15":2,"20":1,"25":1,"30":1,"35":0,"40":0,"45":0,"50":0,"55":1,"60":0,"65":0,"70":0,"75":1,"80":7,"85":10,"90":3,"95":0}
```

order of the object keys:

`"0", "10", "15", "20"..`

and note that these keys are treated as stings not as the int, so the ordering is done by the alphabetical order of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes to your fiddle: jsfiddle.net/adamjld/r9usr4g1/3/

You're better off storing your data in the a controller rather than the HTML. Also, use an array instead of an object.